# Bounded and Feasible of Linear Program?

Tags: terminology, linear-programming

I have a question on usage of terminology in Linear programming.

Why do we have terms like "If an LP is bounded and feasible, then..."

My confusion is, if a Linear program is bounded then it has to have a feasible region, right? I am not sure whether we can have a corner case where a Linear program is bounded and not feasible.

Comment: bounded refers to the objective value not the feasible region.  An LP can have an unbounded feasible region but have an optimal solution and optimal objective value.    In order for the objective value to be unbounded the feasible region also has to be unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

If an LP is not feasible, the question of its boundedness is moot. What's interesting though, is the presence of [unbounded and feasible](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcTL6JMm8CZJa5ioTYY19VEt0NHgDk2_3pCUJeX1H_8tBcRLfB9O) regions. The usage of *feasible and bounded* is necessary when you are talking about a feasible region with finite area.